# Dalvik transformation using wrong invoke- opcode

Tags: android, dalvik, jacoco

I'm running into a problem with the dalvik dex converter and the opcode it is using to invoke methods.  Basically I have a `private final` method defined in my class, and when calling it, instead of generating the `invoke-direct` opcode, dx is generating `invoke-super`.  Because it's a private method, the method doesn't exist on the super class, so I get a VFY violation on the device.  I was able to track down the exact scenario that triggers this, and it appears to happen when:

1. instrumenting the classes with JaCoCo, and
2. classes compiled with `--target 1.6`

If those two conditions are met, the resulting dex class has `invoke-super` instead of `invoke-direct`.  If I disable JaCoCo OR if I compile with `--target 1.5`, it uses the correct `invoke-direct` opcode.

In looking at the `javap` disassembled class code, I can see what causes `dx` to assume super instead of direct:

**Not instrumented, compiled for 1.6:**

```
$ javap -d com.example.ClassName | grep waitForConnectivity
159:    invokespecial   #115; //Method waitForConnectivity:()V
$ dexdump -d classes.dex | grep waitForConnectivity
147ad8: 7010 6042 0200           |001e: invoke-direct {v2}, Lcom/example/ClassName;.waitForConnectivity:()V // method@4260
```

**Instrumented, compiled for 1.5 (`--target 1.5`):**

```
$ javap -d com.example.ClassName | grep waitForConnectivity
235:    invokespecial   #115; //Method waitForConnectivity:()V
$ dexdump -d classes.dex | grep waitForConnectivity
149d4c: 7010 9242 0400           |0018: invoke-direct {v4}, Lcom/example/ClassName;.waitForConnectivity:()V // method@4292
```

**Instrumented, compiled for 1.6:**

```
$ javap -d com.example.ClassName | grep waitForConnectivity
235:    invokespecial   #115; //Method com/example/ClassName.waitForConnectivity:()V
$ dexdump -d classes.dex | grep waitForConnectivity
149d4c: 6f10 9242 0400           |0018: invoke-super {v4}, Lcom/example/ClassName;.waitForConnectivity:()V // method@4292
```

So the difference is that the compiled .class file has compiled java bytecode that references the *fully qualified class name* of the `this` class (notice "`//Method waitForConnectivity:()V`" vs "`//Method com/example/ClassName.waitForConnectivity:()V`").  It appears that `dx` automatically assumes that if the method name is fully qualified, it must use `invoke-super`, but if it's not qualified, it uses `invoke-direct`.

My questions are:

1. Is this a bug in Android's `dx`, or a bug in JaCoCo?
2. How can I avoid this, so that the JaCoCo-instrumented classes can work properly in my automated test builds?

My current workaround is to have a Maven "jacoco" profile, and in there I override the `${java.version}` property to change it from the default "1.6" to "1.5".  Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2):

One of the rules that `dx` uses to determine whether to emit `invoke-super` or `invoke-direct` is whether it believes the method call is being made on the same class as the one doing the calling. See `RopperMachine.java` in the source, around line 912, included here for reference:

```
        case ByteOps.INVOKESPECIAL: {
            /*
             * Determine whether the opcode should be
             * INVOKE_DIRECT or INVOKE_SUPER. See vmspec-2 section 6
             * on "invokespecial" as well as section 4.8.2 (7th
             * bullet point) for the gory details.
             */
            CstMethodRef ref = (CstMethodRef) cst;
            if (ref.isInstanceInit() ||
                (ref.getDefiningClass() == method.getDefiningClass()) ||
                !method.getAccSuper()) {
                return RegOps.INVOKE_DIRECT;
            }
            return RegOps.INVOKE_SUPER;
```

It would be interesting to see a more complete dump of the class that's getting misconverted. I think it's probably the case that what you're seeing from `javap` isn't quite a complete picture of reality. Note that `dx` itself has a .class file dumper built into it which provides a lot more detail than `javap`. Invoke it as `dx --dump --bytes path/to/Name.class`.

Comment: So this would imply that `ref.getDefiningClass() != method.getDefiningClass()`. I'll try to get a more complete dump for you some time today. But the issue appears to be easily reproducible using JaCoCo offline instrumentation and the Java 1.6 compiler. Interestingly though, it was not always breaking like this, so you're probably right that there's something else going on as well. I just don't know when it started.

Comment: I'm granting the bounty because you've satisfied the credible part of the bounty requirement. Although it is not yet resolved or tracked back to a reason/cause, it appears for now that the culprit is most likely the JaCoCo instrumenter, although I feel like `dx` should still be able to recognize that the defining class for the invoked method is equal to the defining class of the invoker, resulting in `INVOKE_DIRECT` as expected. Will require further investigating as suggested. Perhaps we can continue this in a chat at a later time, as I find time to get back to this.

Comment: Thanks! As I said, `dx --dump` can likely help pinpoint the exact nature of the difference. I'm not going to claim that `dx` is faultless (even though pride makes me want to), but yeah, JaCoCo is almost certainly doing something at least somewhat suspect.

Comment: Do you happen to know where to find the "vmspec-2" mentioned in the code comment? Thanks!